# Perform a calculation based upon row values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform a simple calculation (2nd Choice - 1st Choice > 5) and return the rows were that calculation is True, but the columns in the calculation need to change based upon row values.

```
Places  A   B   C   D   E   1st Choice  2nd Choice
Place 1 62  47  43  100 100 A           B
Place 2 64  60  77      100 A           C
Place 3 55  50          0   A           B
Place 4 62  54  100     50  A           B
Place 5 86  50  100     100 A           C
```

The first row would be False bc Col B - Col A = -15, but the second row would be True bc Col C - Col A = 13.

I'm thinking it could be something like this:

```
df[[df[df.column = df['2nd Choice']]-df[df.column = df['1st Choice']]]>5]
```

I have searched quite a bit, but am having a hard time figuring out how to use row values to match the column header in the calculation. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.lookup` and boolean slicing

```
c1 = df.lookup(df.index, df['1st Choice'])
c2 = df.lookup(df.index, df['2nd Choice'])
df[c2 - c1 > 5]

    Places   A   B    C  D    E 1st Choice 2nd Choice
1  Place 2  64  60   77  0  100          A          C
4  Place 5  86  50  100  0  100          A          C
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. One slight tweak - I had to drop any rows which had a Nan in either 1st Choice or 2nd Choice.